# running docker container is not reachable by browser

Tags: node.js, macos, docker

I started to work with docker. I dockerized simple node.js app.  I'm not able to access to my container from outside world (means by browser).

Stack:

- node.js app with 4 endpoints (I used hapi server).
- macOS
- docker desktop community version 2.0.0.2

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD  ["npm","run", "start-server"]
```

I did following steps:

I run from command line from my working dir:

1. `docker image build -t ares-maros .`
2. `docker container run -d --name rest-api -p 8000:8000 ares-maros`
3. I checked if container is running via `docker container ps`
   Here is the result:
   [image] - container is running
4. I open the browser and type `0.0.0.0:8000` (also tried with 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000)
   result:
   [image]
   **So running docker container is not rechable by browser**

I also go into the container typing `docker exec -it 81b3d9b17db9 sh` and try to reach my node-app inside of container via wget/curl and **that's works**. I get responses fron all node.js endpoints.

Where could be the problem ? Maybe my mac can blocked connection ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what OS are you running on your docker machine?

Comment: Try to use the real ip of the server

Comment: Your issue is almost certainly that your node app is bound to 127.0.0.1 and NOT 0.0.0.0 -- which it would have to be to accept requests from another machine (ie, your desktop environment).

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how to change that in server.js

Comment: @MarkDodds macos

Comment: Could be the macOS firewall blocking it.

Comment: @DavidS. Firewall is off

Comment: If you run the command `docker-machine ip` in your mac terminal what does it output?

Comment: @MarkDodds Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

Comment: @PaulBecotte you are right.  node.js server had ip address  127.0.0.1 instead 0.0.0.0

Comment: Run `docker-machine ls`, then get the name of the machine with a 'Running' state, and do `docker-machine ip [name]`

Comment: @MarkDodds that was not problem and I dont think that it's related to this issue

Comment: @Morty your docker machine (the vm used to run the docker container) usually runs on a completely different ip address on your local machine to avoid conflict with localhost (since that is used by your local machine for many things). By running that command you can see what the ip address of the machine is, and i believe using that instead of localhost in the browser will get the application to load

Comment: You can't actually reach the docker containers on a docker-for-mac install by the IP address... those ip addresses in those case are on the virtual linux machine! You CAN bind ports from those containers to the ports on the host mac (which he did)... but you have to set up your application as though it is accepting requests from an external machine (which is usually not the default)

Answer (score -2):

Please check the order of the parameters of the following command:

```
docker container run -d --name rest-api -p 8000:8000 ares-maros
```

I faced a similar. I was using -p port:port at the end of the command. Simply moving it to after 'Docker run' solved it for me.